# Analysis of dynamic connectome data?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, theoretical-biology, artificial-neural-network

I have heard about existence of full brain connectome data of some worms or fishes. I have heard about GEVI - genetically engineered voltage indicators - that allow to see voltage data at subcellular level. My question is: are there available the mentioned data in processed form (approriate for simulation, mathematical analysis, modelling) and, possibly, are there available some analysis and modelling of them? I am searching materials for neural code that is used in brains and those data and analysis would be very helpful for me.

I am aware of enormous body of coarse resolution MRI imaging data. But my question specifically targets connectome/neuron/subneuron level full data and their analysis.

Answer (score 3):

C. Elegans is the only species with a fully characterized connectome and I don't believe there's been much electrophysiological work done on them. The GEVIs are still being optimized and have their own share of issues particularly with signal resolution - distinguishing between subthreshold changes in membrane potential vs action potential. See the [embedded paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4974255/). If anything, it will be awhile before the response properties of the neurons in C. elegans are characterized. However, I'm sure you could try modeling smaller circuits where the connectivity and neural properties of the neurons are known.

Comment: Actually, there seems to be quite a bit of data on C. Elegans. IIRC recently some spiking activity was detected, while earlier it was believed there's none.